# Convert NSData of Image from database to NSString in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata

I am converting NSData of Image from database to NSString in Iphone

Here is my code

```
imageData1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 3) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 3)];           
NSString * Str1 = [NSString base64StringFromData: imageData1 length: [imageData1 length]];
NSData *data1=[NSData base64DataFromString:Str1];
NSString* newStr1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

the length of data is 6511 , but the newstr1 is nil

With reference to this question: I can't create a UTF-8 encoded string out of just any arbitrary binary data from the database - the data needs to actually be UTF-8 encoded. I have aslo done base 64 encoding and decoding. How can I solve this issue. I need it in the format of NSString only, to give it as input to a csv file?

Comment: What is base64StringFromData and base64DataFromString? I can't find them in the Apple SDK. Are they functions you have written?

Comment: i got from  http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html link

Comment: I see - thanks! When you say 'give it as input to a csv file', do you mean you would like the image data to be embedded inside a field of the CSV file itself?

Comment: If i open the csv file in open office i should see the image on one column

Comment: I'm not convinced this is supported in the CSV filetype. I fear you might need to actually export an Excel file to see a decoded image inside the cell....

Comment: How to create an Excel file in iphone? is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps there's an easier way. Making an Excel file is non-trivial. Hopefully someone else can help out as I'm not really sure...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert NSData of Image from database to NSString in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183100/how-to-convert-nsdata-of-image-from-database-to-nsstring-in-iphone)

Comment: (This seems to be a duplicate of your prior question a day earlier, same to the degree that the titles were identical).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ample knowledge of character encoding, but would it not be sufficient to just use the Base 64 encoded string (Str1) in your output?

I fear that re-encoding Str1 as data1 brings you right back to square 1 and undoes any Base 64 encoding done in the line earlier.

Comment: I too have the same doubt , because i did know what should i exactly do.